# Терминал PhpStorm не отображает цвета

Tags: phpstorm, cmd

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После обновления Windows и phpStorm терминал начал отображать символы "?[32m" и "?[39m" вначале и конце строк, также при выводе текстовых сообщений не переводит строки. В терминале использую cmd. Как это исправить, не меняя консольную программу?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153076/webstorm-phpstorm-issue-with-terminal-on-windows-10

Comment: напишите, если поможет. Я тогда перевод в качестве ответа запущу.

Comment: К сожалению ничего не изменилось кроме того, что вместо знаков вопросов начало показывать стрелочки влево